# Heroku Class 'NumberFormatter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, heroku, numberformatter

Deploying my Laravel 7 app in Heroku I get this error, it appears only in Heroku, not on my local box (localhost)

> Class 'NumberFormatter' not found (View: ...)

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

**Server Details**:

- Heroku
- PHP 7.4.12
- Laravel Framework 7.30.4

Comment: please mention laravel version and php version so it help someone to answer

Comment: PHP 7.4.12  and Laravel Framework 7.30.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**NumberFormatter** class<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) requires the [PHP Internationalization extension (`intl`)<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), and this extension is not available built-in on Heroku [Heroku Built-in Extensions<sup>*Heroku Docs*</sup>](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions).

Instead Heroku gives you permission to use [optional extensions<sup>*Heroku Docs*</sup>](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions).

To make use of them you can either use the composer command to require it ("ext-intl"):

```
composer require ext-intl
```

Or you can manually add this to `composer.json` in the [*require* section<sup>*Composer Docs*</sup>](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#the-require-key):

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-intl": "*"
  }
}
```

Commit the file and push the changes to Heroku. The error should be gone until you find the next missing class.

This is another example, why it is a good idea if you have a Composer based PHP project, to document the extensions in use as well in the `composer.json` file.

When the day comes, you have them documented in the Composer JSON already.

And systems like Heroku can benefit from it, too!